# Variable hoisting inside IIFE (lazy parsing)

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I am getting a very strange output on the below scenarios:

```
function test(){
   var test=123;
   console.log(test)
}
// this output : 123

(function test(){
   var test=123;
   console.log(test)
})()

// this output: 123
```

But when using the below code

```
(function test(){
   test=123;
   console.log(test)
})()

//output:

function test(){
    test=123;
    console.log(test)
}
```

Can anybody please explain.

Comment: It's called `hoisting`. Google it.

Comment: @Kinduser: No, that's not hoisting.

Comment: I know hoisting, can you just please explain the behaviour

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Declaring variable inside function without `var` keyword makes it global, it is being hoisted up the script. Isn't it?

Comment: @Kinduser: Nope. :-) `test` within the IIFE refers to the function. (I think you meant "without `var`")

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, it does, because the `test` variable has been **hoisted**.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: but he _assigns_ to `test`. How come it doesn't have effect?

Comment: @Kinduser: No. Again, there's no hoisting there. The creation of the identifier is from the function expression. Hoisting only kicks in for `var` and function **declarations**. (And sort of half-way for `let` and `const`.)

Comment: @AlonEitan: Definitely not a duplicate of that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for letting me know. Retracted my vote

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're seeing isn't related to hoisting.

Your first example is quite straightforward:

```
(function test(){
   var test=123;
   console.log(test)
})()
```

You're creating a variable (via `var`) called `test` within the scope of the function, and assigning it a value, then outputting that value.

Your second example leaves out `var`:

```
(function test() {
    test = 123;
    console.log(test);
})();
```

...and so `test` has quite a different meaning: Within a function created by a named function expression, the function's name is an identifier resolving to the function. So `test` in that code is an identifier for the function.

That identifier is **read-only** when you've used a function expression, so your `test = 123;` line is ignored, and the `console.log` line outputs a representation of the function (as though `test = 123;` weren't there at all).

I'd forgotten that identifier is read-only (when created by an *expression*), but it is: From [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> *FunctionExpression : functionBindingIdentifier ( FormalParameters ) {FunctionBody}*
>
> 1. If the function code for *FunctionExpression* is strict mode code, let *strict* be true. Otherwise let *strict* be false.
> 2. Let *scope* be the running execution context's LexicalEnvironment.
> 3. Let *funcEnv* be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(scope).
> 4. Let *envRec* be *funcEnv*'s EnvironmentRecord.
> 5. Let *name* be StringValue of *BindingIdentifier*.
> 6. **Perform envRec.CreateImmutableBinding(*name*, false).**
> 7. ...

Note Step 6: The binding creating the identifier is *immutable* (can't be changed).

Note that this isn't true for the identifier (binding) created by a function *declaration*, which is mutable; but function *expressions* and function *declarations* treat the identifiers created by the function name completely differently. (For instance: A function declaration puts the name in scope where the declaration is, but a function expression doesn't.)

Comment: Do you know why it is read-only, however without IIFE its overriding the value to 123

Comment: @ankurkushwaha: in the snippet without IIFE you also use `var`

Comment: @ankurkushwaha: in fact, IIFE is irrelevant here. It's the absence or presence of `var` that makes the difference.

Comment: I agree with @ankurkushwaha, why does it work properly when theres no iife? And even with iife, it works when theres `var` keyword. Why does it happen?