# Why can't I modify the function variable in js sometimes?

Tags: javascript

I faced with this weird problem that the function variable in JS is not writable in some case.

```
function a(){
  a=1
  console.log(a)
}
a() // output 1



(function a(){
  a=1
  console.log(a)
})() // output a function 'a'



var b=function a(){
  a=1
  console.log(a)
}
b()  // output is also a function 'a'
```

Comment: yes, things go weird when you try and *misuse* a programming language :p I have no answer, but a question - why would you ever want to do such a thing?

Comment: @Jaromanda X  well, I think everything should be explainable, a bug or by design. I just want to make sense of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this source: [Variable hoisting inside IIFE (lazy parsing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738909/variable-hoisting-inside-iife-lazy-parsing)

The situation you are experimenting is related to the **immutability/mutability** of the identifier/name of a `function` when it is a **function expression** (identifier inmutable) and a **function declaration** (identifier mutable).

In your first example, there is a **function declaration** with identifier `a` (**mutable**), so you are overwriting it inside the method and the output is the result of that overwriting:

```js
function a()
{
    console.log("Without overwrite:", a);
    a = 1; // The identifier `a` is mutable!
    console.log("After overwrite:", a);
}

a();
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

On the second and third examples, you are using **function expressions** where the identifier `a` is **not mutable** (i.e, read-only). So, you can't change it and the output of the console is the function definition:

```js
(function a()
{
    a = 1; // The identifier `a` is not mutable!
    console.log(a);
})();

var b = function aa()
{
    aa = 1; // The identifier `aa` is not mutable!
    console.log(aa);
}

b();
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: If I hadn't already upvoted the answer for correctness, I'd have upvoted it for reskinning the console.